# Drop down on navigation menu not working

Tags: navigation

Any idea why my dropdown menu is not showing up? There should be one under Reserve Now and Features. The litte arrows next to them shows that the menu knows it has children there but the box doesn't open up.

http://inventivewebdesign.com/dev/